# Search string in .txt file in python

Tags: python, search

So i have this file called test

> But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denounc ing
>   pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complet e
>   account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great
>   explo rer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one
>   rejects, disli kes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure,
>   but because those who do no t know how to pursue pleasure rationally
>   encounter consequences that are extremely painful . Nor again is there
>   anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself,
>   because it is  pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in
>   which toil and pain can procure him some great   pleasure. To take a
>   trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
>   exercise, except to ob  tain some advantage from it? But who has any
>   right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure tha  t
>   has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces
>   no resultant pleasure

And this code in python

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.strip()
        if 'trivial' in line:
            print(line)
```

However, it doesn't print anything, but if i replace `'trivial'` for a letter like 't', i'tll print any lines with a 't' on it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me and prints the line with 'trivial' in it

Comment: That should definitely work, the only possibility is that "trivial" is not in the file.

Comment: Im using windows prompt to execute it with python, can that be the problem?

Comment: I guess your file location and the path from which you have opened your prompt might have been different

Comment: Try giving the exact path to your file when you read it

Comment: When you search for just `'t'`, what lines does it print? Do any contain `trivial`?

Comment: when i search for 't' its shown every line that contains a 't', including 'trivial'

Comment: When i print a line, the letters have spaces between them, like if i was "t y p i n g  l i k e  t h i s", should it be like this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it.
Just needed to add enconding utf 16

```
with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'trivial' in line:
            print(line)
```

feels bad man